# Visual Studio: there are no components that can be placed on the toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Windows 7, and a C# / WinForms project. I have a problem that I cannot add any DLLs to the toolbox. I have already tried searching on Google for the answer, but none of the solutions work: rebuilding the project and re-installing Visual Studio both didn't work.

Even if I create a new project, I cannot drag the DLL to the toolbox or nuGet or use "Choose Item" from the toolbox. I want to use materialSkin, metroframework, and others like that.

Just in case it helps: I have installed Visual C# 2008 and Visual Studio 2010 previously; could that cause any problems with Visual Studio 2013?

Here is the error I see:

[image]

Can anyone help please?

Comment: SO is not the right place, use the project's bug tracker at github to report issues.  Keep in mind that you have to show some evidence of following the install instructions, they will completely ignore you when you only post that screenshot and won't explain why you did not use the recommended procedure.  Much like we will here.

Comment: Thank you , Hans Passant , i will report it  . Although i found the problem is that not only the metroFramework , other dll i cannot place to toolbox too,Therefore i thought thats the problem of visual studio